# Has Zoro attacked with "Three Thousand Worlds" in the time between Baratie and Dressrosa?

Tags: one-piece

Zoro confessed that he got defeated by Dracule Mihawk using his "Three Thousand World" attack in the Baratie Restaurant, when he first met him. I was wondering if he used this attack anytime after that before we see him use it again on Pica in Dressrosa. If so, in which fight?

Comment: The first time they fight it's in episode 24, the whole fight is in this episode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, he does. Zoro first uses uses his secret move "Three Thousand Realms" against Mihawk on the Baratie to little effect, and it isn't used again for hundreds of chapters until being used successfully against Oars to give him three very large scars and a lot of damage when the Strawhats successfully incapacitate him.

Comment: Did he really announced that he attacks with "3000 Worlds"? I can't recall in which point of the fight he attacked him like this, can you quote me the episode?

Answer (score 4):

As Qiri mentioned, he did use it against Oars in thriller back. This takes place in chapter 480. Below is a picture showing the attack, with the "Three thousand worlds" editor's translation.

[image]